# Page navigation in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am a beginner in extjs.I am doing a application which is having multiple page with one page presented at a time.From the intial page in a button click i want present the next page.I am able to do this in a card layout.How can this be done in other layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Card layout helps you swap pages (make one page visible and all its siblings not). That means in other layouts you must do it manually.

Have you a reason use different layout?

Comment: Is cardlayout the usual way of doing a standard application with page navigation in extjs,because i did not read in any extjs tutorials about using card layout for navigation.

Comment: yes it is a usual practice, you can also checkout some examples sources (from docs site)